# apache plugin for NTLM for Getting log in user name

Tags: apache

This looks similar to my previous question of Apache NTLM plug in.
I need to get the  login user names for the all the who sen the request to web server(Apache server).we use windows authentication NTLM for authenticate users.
               For  microsoft IIS server its really simple, as it is set in server variable.
I want it for Apache server.Does any one know any  Plugin that does the same thing as done by IIS for apache.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i got the issue resolved,
I used the JCIFS Plug in which will authenticate and give me the user ID and IP  Address of the clients that are requesting to the Apache server.

detailed information is given [here](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html)